# Generating random data in two tables with 1:M relationship with more cells of unique data in the second table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables: `first_table` and `other_table`. I'm generating 3 rows of random data in the `pr_key` column in the `first_table`. The `first_table` and `other_table` have a 1:M relationship.

For each `pr_key` in the `other_table` I need to generate again random numbers in the `second_code` column so that there would be in total 9 rows.

The problem with my approach is, that the random numbers in the `second_code` column repeat for each `pr_key`, but they need to be different.

Additionally, in the `other_table` there is a constraint, that checks, that the pairs of pr_key and second_code are unique.

```
with oper as (
INSERT INTO first_table(
    pr_key,
)
SELECT
    pr_key,
FROM (
    SELECT(
        SELECT (random()*10)::int+(gen*0) as pr_key
    ),
    gen as id
    FROM generate_series(1,3) as gen
    ) main
RETURNING pr_key)    
INSERT INTO other_table(pr_key, second_code) 
SELECT pr_key, second_code
FROM oper, (
    SELECT
   (
        SELECT 1+(random()*10)::int+(gen*0) as second_code
   ),
    gen as id
    FROM generate_series(1,3) as gen
   ) AS gener
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this syntax:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE t1 (pr_key int);
> CREATE TABLE t2 (pr_key int, second_code int);
> ```

> ```
> with c1 as
> (
>     insert into t1 
>     select pr_key
>     from (
>            select (select (random()*10)::int+(gen*0) as pr_key),
>            gen as id
>            from generate_series(1,3) as gen
>          ) t
>     returning pr_key
> )
> insert into t2 (pr_key, second_code)
> select pr_key, (select (random()*10)::int+(id*0))
> from c1, (select gen as id from generate_series(1,3) as gen) t2
> ```

> ```
> select * from t1;
> ```
>
> ```
> | pr_key |
> | -----: |
> |      2 |
> |      7 |
> |      9 |
> ```

> ```
> select * from t2;
> ```
>
> ```
> pr_key | second_code
> -----: | ----------:
>      2 |           5
>      2 |           7
>      2 |           1
>      7 |           4
>      7 |           0
>      7 |           3
>      9 |           4
>      9 |          10
>      9 |           2
> ```